# CSS 2 columns layout with display:table

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a 2 columns layout in CSS, with the property `display: table;`, but there is an image on the top of the second columns, and the content of the columns is limited in height, so the extra-content from the first column goes on the second column.

Here is an illustration of what I'm trying to do:

```
Here is some text in        IMAGE
the first column, and   
I want that text to go      everything is displayed
on the second column,       with the help of CSS.
under the image. And
```

I know it can be done with `display: grid`, or `display: flex`, or even `float`, but these are not an option... (nor Javascript) :(

I've made several searches but nothing led to the proper result.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can have the text overflow into columns using... [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns), but you wont be able to position an image like that. Generally  believe that is the only way to have text ioverflow that way  in CSS. Even grid or flex won't help you there. BTW why aren't other methods allowed? Just "forbidding" without reason is frustrating for people wanting to help, and will probably cause fewer answers.

Comment: Thanks @RoToRa, you're right. I used the ```columns```property and I was able to have some kind of results, but not the one I was seeking for. The reason to use only the ```table```property is because I convert HTML to PDF. And unfortunately, the last technologies (like ```Flex```or ```Grid```) are not properly converted. I guess I might have to consider another one, then ;) Thanks again !